# Momentum strategies as a private investor

Tags: investing, etf, mutual-funds

I like to invest in a fund or ETF that invests itself according to the momentum strategies described in the paper by [Jegadeesh and Titman](http://www.business.unr.edu/faculty/liuc/files/BADM742/Jegadeesh_Titman_1993.pdf), i.e. investing into stock with recent strong performance and going short on stocks with recent weak performance.

While various products contain "Momentum" in the product name [(such as this by Vanguard)](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/VFMO), these products commonly only invest into stocks with recent appreciation. Is there a mutual fund (preferably by a large and well-established provider) available to private investors which implements both going long and short? I wonder if short selling is considered too risky as part of an ETF or mutual fund to be implemented?

Comment: There are certainly inverse ETFs that go short an index they aim to reverse the performance of, but I don’t know about one for momentum.

Comment: So - you want to have a "momentum" ETF that goes long high momentum stocks and short low momentum stocks?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @DStanley. That's indeed what I was looking for.